# Does it make sense to have one possibility in an OR() clause?

Tags: formula

I've been asked to clean up some old formulas from before I was hired. I don't understand what I'm seeing. Does it make sense to have an OR clause with just one option? For instance:

```
AND(
$Setup.Validation__c.BypassValidation__c = FALSE,
OR(
ISPICKVAL (Stage__c, "Delay")  
),
ISBLANK (Reason__c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't hurt much besides making the formula harder to read (i.e. it takes more mental effort to understand what it is trying to do compared to doing it "the right way").
But it also accomplishes nothing, so it should be removed.

Comment: You can also turn `$Setup.Validation__c.BypassValidation__c = FALSE,` into `NOT($Setup.Validation__c.BypassValidation__c)`. That one's more a matter of preference (i.e. what is easier for you to read?)

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've left in the

```
OR (
 condition
)
```

if in dealing with the business, I've gotten "vibes" that a second, third, ... condition is likely to be added "soon" so I might as well get the structure in place to easily extend with the additional OR conditions